# Problem in finding duplicates in a string using bit manipulation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bit-manipulation

I think, I have implemented a right logic to find whether a string contains duplicates or not but even after that nothing is printing in terminal, and I am unable to understand why it is so what are the mistakes in this program I have done. can any explain it why it's not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char A[] = "finiding\0";
    long int H = 0;
    long int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; A[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        x = 1;
        int temp = A[i];
        x = x << (temp - 97);
        if (x & H > 0) {
            printf(" %c duplicate found !", A[i]);
        } else {
            H = x | H;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked the loop body is executing 7 times which is desired according to string "finding" but the control is not entering into the if else block written into the for-loop body and I am unable to understand why it so.

here I have used `H` (initialized with zero) as hashing variable, where I am setting up the bit in `H` corresponding to the ASCII code of character coming inside the loop each time using concept of merging. and if the bit is already set then printing "Duplicate found!". although there is no error in code but even it's not working.

Comment: ok, i have tried again but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `char A[] = "finiding\0";` has 2 null terminators for no reasons and with no effect.
- `int temp = A[i];` may set `temp` to a negative number if `char` is signed by default on your platform and if the string contains non-ASCII characters.
- `x = x << (temp - 97);` does not work for characters outside the range `97` to `128`, and it may actually overflow for some of these characters.  The code has undefined behavior for characters below `'a'`, such as digits and capital letters.
- you probably meant `x = 1UL << (temp - 97);` instead, but this still does not account for 88% of all possible 8-bit byte values.
- `if (x & H > 0)` is incorrect too as it is parsed as `if (x & (H > 0))`.  You should write `if ((x & H) > 0)`

Your approach does not work because there are more byte values than bits in a `long int`.  You should use an array of bytes:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char flag[UCHAR_MAX+1] = { 0 };
    const char *s = "finiding";
    while (*s) {
        unsigned char uc = *s++;
        if (flag[uc]) {
            printf("%c duplicate found!\n", uc);
        }
        flag[uc] = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your program and indeed received no output.  However, it should be pointed out that during the compilation, I received a warning from the compiler for this line of code.

```
if(x&H > 0){
```

The warning was a suggestion for including additional parentheses to insure proper precedence in the testing.

```
warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘&’ [-Wparentheses]|
```

Utilizing the warning and recommended usage of parentheses, the line of code was changed to the following.

```
if((x&H) > 0){
```

Once that was done and the program recompiled, following was the output produced at the terminal.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Dupes/bin/Release$ ./Dupes 
 i duplicate found ! i duplicate found ! n duplicate found
```

The takeaway from this is that one needs to review any and all compiler warnings when building a program or project.  Give that bit of refactored code a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.